# Map of Spratley and Scarborough Shoal EEZs

Tags: mapping, china

I have scoured the internet looking for a map of the South China Sea that shows the disputed Spratly Islands and Scarborough Shoal along with the EEZ (200 nm) associated with them.

In other words, one of the big disputes of course is whether these features are "islands" which give the 200 nm exclusive economic zones (EEZ) all around. Assuming that the features are islands (and not low-tide elevations or rocks), I'm looking for a map that shows the islands plus their putative EEZ.

You can find lots of maps of the South China Sea, and they will often include markings for the EEZs of the countries. But the hot dispute is over a) who owns the features in the ocean, and b) whether you can get an EEZ go to with it. I'm interested in the latter question and I'm looking for a map to show what they'd look like if indeed recognized.

Comment: https://storymaps.arcgis.com/stories/f41484de9d4144c59b22540cb94b150a - 5 min of search

Comment: Erik, thanks for the gift of your 5 minutes. That helps.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Comment: Thanks. I will go there.